# The navbar does not get all the width of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, row, navbar

[image]

So my navbar does not get the full width of the screen . On bottom right there is an empty space which I do not know how to cover. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you talking about the grey footer area? And the fact that it is dropped down below the white cube logo??

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the white cube log is in a block level element, so that it takes up a line and forces your navbar below it. (hence the gap).

To solve that you'll need to either `float` the navbar and the logo container away from each other; or set them `display: inline-block;`